# Firebase .push() throws 'permission_denied' error

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-security

When creating entering new data with .push(), like so:

```
var passes = chatRef.push('passes');
    passes.set({
      userID: FirebaseRef.user.id, 
      gymName: $(this.options.data.gymName.getContent()).text().split(/[ ]+/).join(' '), 
      price: $(this.options.data.price.getContent()).text().split(/[ ]+/).join(' '),
      numDays: window.gymDays
    })
```

I get the following alert from Firebase:

FIREBASE WARNING: set at /-JPBDARJ67cnr6Yr_nGZ failed: permission_denied

My Security Rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      ".write": true,
      "$userid": {
        ".read": "auth.id == $userid",
        ".write": true
      }
    },
    "passes": {
     ".write": true
    }
  }
}
```

Any idea how to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here occurs when you call `var passes = chatRef.push('passes');`. You're actually creating a new child at this point, not just accessing the child "passes". Your security rules allow you to write to "passes", but they aren't allowing you to *create* "passes".

To solve the problem, get rid of the line `var passes = chatRef.push('passes');` and replace it with `var passes = chatRef.child('passes');`. That way, it will be accessing a child in Firebase, not creating one.

**EDIT:**

For adding children, use .push():

```
passes.push({
  userID: FirebaseRef.user.id, 
  gymName: $(this.options.data.gymName.getContent()).text().split(/[ ]+/).join(' '), 
  price: $(this.options.data.price.getContent()).text().split(/[ ]+/).join(' '),
  numDays: window.gymDays
});
```

Comment: Thanks Timothy. I was originally using .child() but each time a new pass was created it would overwrite the last pass created so that there was never more than one pass in the database at once. I essentially want to create a list of passes and have each new pass append to the list.

Comment: You could use push({ data }) instead of set({ data }).

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code, using .push(), in which passes are saved to whichever user is logged in:

```
var BASE_URL = 'ENTER YOUR FIREBASE URL';
var chatRef = new Firebase(BASE_URL);

var passes = chatRef.child('passes').child(FirebaseRef.user.id);
passes.push({
  userID: FirebaseRef.user.id, 
  gymName: $(this.options.data.gymName.getContent()).text().split(/[ ]+/).join(' '), 
  price: $(this.options.data.price.getContent()).text().split(/[ ]+/).join(' '),
  numDays: window.gymDays
});
```

And here's how to call passes by a particular user:

```
var array = []

FirebaseRef.chatRef.child('passes').child(FirebaseRef.user.id).limit(100).on('child_added', function(snapshot) {this.array.push(snapshot.val())}.bind(this));
```